# Adding a 'I am already in the channel function' to a bot. [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a feature where if a bot is already in a voice chat with someone and the person tries to make it join, the bot replies 'I am already in the voice chat'.
Here's the part where it would fit in

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  // Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
  // we ignore it
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content === '>join') {
    // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    } else {
      message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
    }
  }
});
```

A person that I asked, suggested I used I compare the 'voiceState.channelID' of the bot and the user. If its the same, then the bot returns the message 'I am already in the channel!' where and how would I fit this into the code. I am very new to programming and JavaScript.

Extra info: I am using node.js and a library called Discord.js. If you could not tell, this is a Discord bot.
I have only included a segment of the code dedicated to voice chat, please tell me if you need the rest and I will provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Discord.JS you can do `member.voice.channelID` to get the channel ID. SO, in your code you could add:

```
const clientMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

if(!clientMember.voice.channel) {
    //The bot is in no voice channel, go ahead and join it.

} else if(clientMember.voice.channelID == message.member.voice.channelID) {
    //They're already in the same channel

} else {
    //They're both connected to a voice channel, but they are in different channels.
}
```

Put that inside the `if (message.member.voice.channel) {` to make sure the person that ran the command is actually in a VC.